# How to slice SparseVector with Breeze?

Tags: sparse-matrix, scala-breeze

I have a SparseVector in Breeze and a given list of indices. How do I get a new SparseVector containing elements present only at those indices?

Eg:

```
import breeze.linalg.{Vector => BV, DenseVector => BDV, SparseVector => BSV}
val testVector = new BSV(Array(1,2,3), Array(1,2,3), 10)
val indices = Array(1,2)
```

I want to get a new vector like this:

```
val sliceVector = testVector.slice(indices)  // Vector(1,2)
```

I can't iterate through indices and values manually as I have over a million indices with just 2000 non-zero values.

Answer (score 2):

`testVector(indices.toIndexedSeq)` will return a SliceVector representing a view of the underyling vector. I think that does what you want here.

Comment: Thanks!! I din't know it was that simple. Although, how do I convert this SliceVector to a new SparseVector?